# Logging signal strength in router logs

Tags: linux

how to know the client(device) signal strength that connected to WiFi in OpenWrt platform?

Is it possible to to log signal strength of devices connected to Wi-Fi access point? Actually not even just connected devices, but would it be possible to intercept all wireless traffic and record the signal strength of each intercepted packet?

Comment: Try this bash script, https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=29075