# Wi-Fi signal strength in OpenWRT

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wireless-router, openwrt

Is there a way to retrieve signal strengths on all the devices connected in a wireless network in OpenWRT?
I want to check signal strength of devices connected to the router. My router has OpenWRT kernel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging signal strength in router logs](http://superuser.com/questions/935900/logging-signal-strength-in-router-logs)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it’s quite simple, actually: `iw dev wlan0 station dump`. [Here’s the relevant documentation.](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw#getting_station_statistics).

Some guy on [OpenWrt’s forums](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=27581) made a script that lists associated stations and also looks up IP addresses and host names for these stations. I adapted it to use `iw` instead of the outdated `wl` command:

```
#! /bin/ash
ifaces="wlan0 wlan1"

for iface in $ifaces
do
  echo $iface
  stations=`iw dev $iface station dump | grep Station | awk '{print $2}'`

  for sta in $stations
  do
    echo "------------------------------------------------------"
    iw dev $iface station get $sta
    echo -e "\t ---"
    grep $sta /proc/net/arp | awk '{print "\t IP: "$1" (from ARP table)"}'
    grep -i $sta /var/dhcp.leases | awk '{print "\t IP: "$3" (from DHCP Lease)\n\t NAME: "$4" (from DHCP Lease)"}'
  done
  echo "------------------------------------------------------"
done
```

Please note that my router has two wireless NICs, which your router may not have. Adjust the `ifaces` variable accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**I'm using my OpenWRT router as a repeater** and I used Daniel's post to write this script to keep updating me on the WiFi signal strength of my **already connected base station** while setting up my antenna line of sight. *(use Ctrl+c to stop execution)*

```
#!/bin/bash
iface="wlan0"
while true
do
    clear
    iw dev $iface station dump | grep 'signal:\|beacon signal'
    let "x++"
    echo Read Count: $x
    sleep 1
done
```